# Blazor JS Interop call confusion

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor

The following has two syntax errors of wrong type, however, I can't find any documentation on how this should be used and what I'm doing wrong. What parameters am I suppose to give this `open` function?

```
    Syntax error 1 - Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Threading.CancellationToken'   
    Syntax error 2 - Argument 3: cannot convert from 'string' to 'object[]'
```

```html
private async Task HelloWorld()
{
       string url = "https://www.google.com";
       await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("open", url, "_blank");
}
```

Comment: I'd expect it to be something like `await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("open", new object[] { url, "_blank" });` based on the method signature: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.jsinterop.jsruntime.invokeasync?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: that will throw the following `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>(string, object[])'
` this is something I was trying to get to work, but I am obviously missing something.

Comment: Well, you need to actually have an instance, which can be injected, as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: This seems like total overkill, there is no way all this is necessary, right? I have been reading it and it seems like ridiculous.

Comment: I guess this is the only way. Thanks!

Comment: Do you get the error at compile time ?

Answer (score 3):

`JSRuntime` is an abstract class with no static method so you can not call `InvokeAsync` method of the class itself. To execute javascript you have to inject an `IJSRuntime` object :

```
public class MyClass{
  
 private readonly IJSRuntime js;
 public MyClass(IJSRuntime js){
       this.js=js;
   }

    private async Task HelloWorld()
    {
           string url = "https://www.google.com";
           await js.InvokeAsync<object>("open", url, "_blank");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit tricky to tell what is really going on without seeing more of your code, both on the JS side and on the razor side. However, here is a simple example of calling a JS function within your C# code. Btw, I am assuming (hopefully correctly!) that you are doing this within a component, because they code is slightly different for calling this in a class. Also, it would be helpfult to see what, if anything, you are returning from the JS method:

**C#**

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

@code {
    private async Task HelloWorld()
    {
        string url = "https://www.google.com";
        await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("open", url, "_blank");
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    window.open = function (url, target) {
        console.log(url, target)
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had this in the top of the page:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JsRuntime;
```

And my method looked like this:

```
private async void OpenSettings()
{
    await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("Alert", nameof(OpenSettings));
}
```

Apparently I had a typo, so I was calling `JSRuntime` and not `JsRuntime` (notice the small "s").

Comment: In case it helps someone who doesn't have a typo: I was making the method call from a partial class instead of the razor page. By moving my method call to the razor page's code block, it correctly interpreted the arguments as a parameter array and the error went away.